# having problem with updating model entity framework in database-first approach

Tags: .net, entity-framework, database-first, mappingexception

I've used entity framework in my projects and i used database-first approach
almost in each time that i change the database ( adding/removing a field to existing table or add new table ) after updae the model , it's becaming unvalid and i receive some strange and irrational errors.

for example :
Column 'XXX' specified as part of this MSL does not exist in MetaDataWorkspace

or

Error 10021: Duplicated Schema element encountered.
or System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException

and i must do some unrelated task such as

deleteing all tables from model ,
closing and reopening the visual studio ,
undo pending changes ,
deleteing all project data , etc ...

to releave these errors.

what's the problem ? did i do somethings wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days searching I found the solution. Try this:

1 Delete all tables or fields which you added to emdx file ( back to previous state ) and give a successful rebuild.

2 Add new fields and tabales.

3 Save emdx file.

4 Right click on emdx file and click on "Run Custom Tool".

5 Rebulid the project.

If your problem isn't solved, try to substitute step 2 with step 3.